# R: Calculate correlation for every n number of rows

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (34707060 obs) that consists of accelerometer data for *X,Y,Z*. Data was collected at 30Hz, meaning I have 30 rows of data for each second. See head of my data below.

```
                Timestamp      X      Y     Z
1 30/06/2021 08:00:00.000 -1.109 -1.559 1.508
2 30/06/2021 08:00:00.034 -0.688 -1.043 0.891
3 30/06/2021 08:00:00.067 -0.363 -0.531 0.555
4 30/06/2021 08:00:00.100 -0.164 -0.496 0.816
5 30/06/2021 08:00:00.134  0.063 -0.363 0.496
6 30/06/2021 08:00:00.167 -0.098 -0.992 0.227
```

I am compressing this dataset so it shows me values for each second. I am able to calculate the mean, minimum, maximum, sum, standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis for every 30 rows (compressing into 1 row, representing 1 second) using the following line of code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(sec = floor_date(dmy_hms(Timestamp), "second")) %>% 
  summarise(Timestamp = first(Timestamp),
            across(-Timestamp, 
                   list(mean = mean, min = min, max = max, sum=sum, skew=skewness, kurt=kurtosis),
                   .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))
```

Now I would also like include the correlation between *XY*, *XZ* and *YZ* in the above code, so it calculates the correlation for every second (see example below).

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(sec = floor_date(dmy_hms(Timestamp), "second")) %>% 
  summarise(Timestamp = first(Timestamp),
            across(-Timestamp, 
                   list(mean = mean, min = min, max = max, sum=sum, skew=skewness, kurt=kurtosis, 
                        cor1=cor(X,Y)),
                   .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))
```

This, however, gives me the following error:

```
> Error in `summarise()`: ! Problem while computing `..2 = across(...)`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 4: sec = 2021-06-30 08:00:03. Caused by
> error in `as_across_fn_call()`: ! Can't convert `fn`, a number, to a
> function. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can someone help me adjust the code, if this is possible, to have it also calculate the correlation for every 30 rows?

Comment: I think you just need to move `cor1=cor(X,Y))` outside of the `list` and `across` and put it after `Timestamp = first(Timestamp)` e.g. `summarise(Timestamp = first(Timestamp), cor1=cor(X,Y)),......`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. I unfortunately cannot accept your answer as the correct one, as you commented. I also put it after the list, rather than before. Otherwise it also calculates the mean, sum, min etc for the correlation, which I do not need. Putting it after the list (and .names does not do this.